# VBA Call to SQL Stored Procedure Causing Other Pages to hang

Tags: vba, sql-server-2005

I've got a simple piece of code that executes a SQL Server backup.

```
 With sCmd
    .ActiveConnection = sCN
    .CommandText = "dbo.csp_ad_hoc_single_full_backup"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

    .Parameters.Refresh
    .Parameters("@database_name").Value = strDB
    .Parameters("@backup_dir").Value = preBackup_directory
    .Parameters("@backup_dir_space").Value = objDiskSpace
    .Execute , , adAsyncExecute

End With    

returnvalue = sCmd.parameters(0)
```

This code executes when the user hits the page, the return value then displays a different text per each possible result of the procedure.

The problem is that I cannot hit any other pages while this procedure runs. I've tried using 'adAsyncExecute', but that does not seem to work. The page that displays the results and runs this code does not load until the entire backup completes. I wonder if perhaps this is why other pages hang.

Any ideas?

Comment: VBA will not continue until the `.Execute` process completes.

Comment: @enderland Any suggestion on a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per enderland's comment, VBA will not continue until the `.Execute` process completes.

My solution is to simply write the parameters sql table instead of immediately trying to execute the procedure. The web page will display the table write as sucessful. A job will then pick up those parameters and execute the code as it would have upon page load originally. The user will be notified of the job's completion via email using `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail` a the end of the job.